# Is it possible to have windows which are independent of the workspace?

Tags: 3d-view

What I am looking for is the ability of having independent windows that retain their type and shading/viewport settings when I change workspace. What seems to happen is that each workspace changes each of these independent windows to the last used state (or how you defined the startup file if you are just starting Blender). Is it possible to have windows not linked to workspaces? Thanks.

Comment: I think that's only possible with floating windows, for example the one that opens as the preference tab.

Comment: "View/Area/Duplicate area..." will give an independant window not related to the workspace..

Comment: Holy crap, lemon, I have a dual monitor setup, and you just saved me a lifetime of tab-switching! I've been using blender a long time, and never knew you could (or even thought to do) this. This deserves to be an answer in it's own right, in my opinion,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *"view/area"* menus have a *"duplicate area into new window"* which gives an independant window that is not related to the workspace.

[image]

Comment: I'll add that once this new viewport exists, you can use the "editor type" selection button in the top left to make it any kind of editor window you want - Amazing for multi-monitor setups!